# In which Android version was "emoji" support officially introduced?

Tags: android, unicode, emoji

I've made an app that shows a timeline and for each item it shows how many Comments and Votes it has. To save space, i used emojis, like so:

```
 0   0
```

But when I run the app on Android 2.3, it shows me two squares, like so:

```
□ 0  □ 0
```

Now I decided to replace the emojis to plain text when the Android version hasn't "emoji"-support, but for that I need to know in which Android version that feature was implemented, in order to perform the check.
I only have Android 2.3 and 5.1 to test here... So I need to know, if anyone knows in which version this was implemented.

Thanks

Comment: Best way is to implement youself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 4.1 was the first to officially support emoji, however some devices still may not have emoji support.